# new admin wondering why htop and top show different numbers on scientific linux VM

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, scientific-linux, htop

I am trying to figure out if I am using htop correctly.  A top on this VM reveals:

```
top - 17:52:39 up 98 days, 23:05,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.01, 0.00
Tasks: 178 total,   1 running, 177 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si, 98.9%st
Mem:   7025100k total,  2956284k used,  4068816k free,    12276k buffers
Swap:  8191992k total,   729080k used,  7462912k free,  1756724k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
25778 manga     20   0 1052m 228m 3228 S  1.3  3.3 959:15.39 python             
26343 manga     20   0 1054m 231m 3208 S  1.0  3.4 938:22.52 python             
25712 manga     20   0  988m 225m 3208 S  0.7  3.3 948:48.92 python             
26316 manga     20   0 1054m 234m 3200 S  0.7  3.4 930:13.21 python             
15500 root      20   0  102m 4664 3612 S  0.3  0.1   0:01.12 sshd               
    1 root      20   0 19360  652  420 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.22 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:30.26 kthreadd           
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  18:54.61 migration/0  
.... etc ...
```

While an HTOP on the same machine shows what looks to be maxed out CPUs?

[image]

Am I reading this right?  Or is it reversed and that is how 'free' the cpus are?

Comment: I think it does, they say orange (more yellow to me) but looks like a high steal time, which implies the storage is waiting on the CPU? So maybe I need to add more CPUs to the VM if users are complaining of slowness.

Comment: No, it's not storage your VM is waiting for, it most probably is another VM on the same hypervisor, or multiple other VMs, "stealing" CPU time from your VM.

Comment: They match (almost perfectly). But did you saw this: `98.9%st`?

Comment: @Lenniey ahh okay, I wasn't sure the KVM managed vms were 'smart' enough to steal cpu from this VM.  I am assuming this means they need the compute power more than this VM does.  I need to read up on KVM I guess to unravel how all this I inherited was configured.